# Regexp negate xml element name

Tags: php, xml, regex

this maybe dumb question but could someone please negate this regexp for me?

```
$reg = '/^(?!XML)[a-z][\w0-9-]*$/i';
```

I've tried [^...] but not really works or I'm just doing it wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also recommend you using `\A` and `\z`, instead of `^` and `$`. **`$` may contain LF.**

Comment: I noticed `[\w0-9-]` equals to `[\w-]`.

Answer (score 1):

`[^...]` syntax works only for character classes. Outside a character class, `^` asserts position at the beginning of the line. It cannot be used to negate a regular expression itself. What you can do it instead, is to do the negation using the PHP code: `if(!preg_match(...))`

```
$reg = '/^(?!XML)[a-z][\w0-9-]*$/i';

if(!preg_match($reg, $stuff)) {
    # code...
}
```

However, if you're going to work with XML / HTML, then a regex isn't probably the best way. **Use an XML parser instead.** That way, you can be sure that your code doesn't break when the format of the mark up changes.

Comment: Functions **simplexml_load_file** and **simplexml_load_string** are bundled in plain PHP5.

Comment: Thanks for the reply the things is I need the regexp "negation" for the preg_replace essentially need to replace wrong characters in a XML element name so !preg_match isn't exactly what I need.

Comment: So, what is your final goal?

Comment: The best solution for me would be to be able to preg_replace the "negation" of the above mentioned regexp something like this - preg_replace(!$reg,"-",$string) if it's possible

Comment: @user3415263: Try using a positive lookahead with `preg_replace`, like so: `$reg = '/^(?=XML)[a-z][\w0-9-]*$/'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$positive = '\A(?!XML)[a-z][\w-]*+\z';
$negative = "(?!$positive)\A";
```